# How to avoid duplicate dates in x axis in Victory Chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, victory-charts

I try to draw a graph with Victory Chart, and the main axis values are dates fetched from database.
I define my main axis as below

```
<VictoryAxis
        // main axis styles
        scale={{x: 'time'}}
        style={{
            tickLabels: {
                fontSize: 12,
                fontFamily: 'Nunito',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
        }}
        tickCount={6}
        // define the format of the main axis dates
        tickFormat={(x) => {
            const dateObj = new Date(x);
            const year = dateObj.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
            const month = dateObj.toLocaleString('fr-fr', { month: '2-digit' });
            return `${month}/${year}`;
        }}
       fixLabelOverlap={true}
    />
```

The data are defined as below :

```
<VictoryLine
        interpolation="monotoneX"
        labelComponent={(
        <VictoryTooltip
            style={{
                fontSize: 10,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
            }}
            flyoutStyle={{
                stroke: 'tomato',
                strokeWidth: 0,
                fill: '#f87268',
            }}
        />
        )}
        style={{
            data: { stroke: '#f87268' },
            parent: {
                border: '1px solid #ccc',
                fontFamily: 'Nunito',
            },
        }}
        domain={{
            y: [0, 10]
        }}
        data={petWeight.map((item) => {
            if (item.weightDate && item.weightValue) {
                return { x: new Date(item.weightDate), y: item.weightValue };
            }
        })}
        animate={{
            duration: 1500,
            onLoad: { duration: 1000 },
        }}
    />
```

[image]

I want to remove the dates duplicates in x-axis, I have read the documentation but couldn't find the solution.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should be responsible for handling duplicate date case, not the library itself. One sample approach is to merge values that have the same weightDate, calculate their avarage weightValue to display.

Comment: It's strange because if I just add an item, there are no more duplicates, only 4 dates as tick values :o

Comment: And I don't have duplicates in my data, juste 2 dates "06/07/2015" and "08/09/2015", so why  do I have 07/15 twice and 08/15 three times in my tick values ?

Comment: Then you should provide a working sample with data (petWeight) so I can help you :)

Comment: Ok, this is the graph after adding a new item :  ![graph](https://imgur.com/BT2FiKN)
You can see the added item below the graph, and the dates in x-axis are ok.